# AngularJS qTip Without jQuery UI

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, qtip2, qtip

I am looking for an AngularJS directive that creates tooltips similar to que ones on qTip but I do not want to bring jQuery UI into my component. Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: can you use this https://github.com/romainberger/angular-qtip2-directive

Comment: I have to verify that that does not require jQuery UI. I don't want to add jQuery UI to my bundle of files.